# Laravel 4 saving image with Dropzone

Tags: database, model, laravel-4, save, dropzone.js

I'm trying to save images with Dropzone.js in my Laravel 4 project.

This is my code:

```
$fileInput = Input::file('file');

    if(Input::hasFile('file'))
    {

        $fileName = Hash::make($fileInput->getClientOriginalName());

        $path = public_path().'/images/';

        $fileType = $fileInput->guessExtension();

        $fileSize = $fileInput->getClientSize()/1024;

        $file           =   new Image;
        $file->nombre   =   $fileName;
        $file->ruta     =   $path;
        $file->tipo     =   $fileType;
        $file->size     =   $fileSize;
        $file->user_id  =   Sentry::getUser()->id;

        if($fileInput->move($path, $fileName.'.'.$fileInput->guessExtension()))
        {
            $file->save();
        }

    }
```

I'm obtaining the next error message:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to undefined method Intervention\\Image\\Facades\\Image::save()","file":"\/Applications\/XAMPP\/xamppfiles\/htdocs\/webs\/lara4\/edu1\/app\/controllers\/ImageController.php","line":74}}
```

So... my problem is that I can't save my image in my Data Base. I save the image in my server, but not in my DB. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had a model called 'Image', and I'm using `Intervention`. So, there was a conflict. I've solved it changing the `'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'` for `'Img' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'`.

Now it works, but I don't know if it is a really good practice... Any other suggestion?